# Simplest way to change the border of a textfield on error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom-events

I am trying to figure out the easiest way to put a red border around a text field if it doesn't follow a specific format. My code is property detecting if the text is in the correct format but I am having trouble changing the border color when the check fails. I would prefer to only use html/css and JavaScript if possible but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

This is my html for the text box:

```
<p class="fieldtitle"> First Name </p>
<span><input type="text" class="textinput" id="fname" name="fname" /></span>
```

This is my JavaScript to check if it's in the correct format:

```
function chkfName() {
    var myfname = document.getElementById("fname");
    var pos = myfname.value.search(/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/);

    if (pos != 0) {
        //this is where I want to change the border around the text box
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change it pretty easily like this!

```
function chkfName() {
var myfname = document.getElementById("fname");
var pos = myfname.value.search(/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/);

if (pos != 0) {
    fname.style.borderColor = "red";
    return false;
} else
    return true;
```

}

Here is some documentation on it: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a stylesheet class `.error`
Toggle it with JS using [`Element.classlist.toggle`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
function chkfName() {
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
  var pos = /^[\w'-]{2,32}$/.test(fname.value);
  fname.classList.toggle("error", !pos);
  return pos;
}

document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", chkfName);
```

```css
.error{border:2px solid red;}
```

```html
<form>
  <p class="fieldtitle"> First Name </p>
  <span><input type="text" class="textinput" id="fname" name="fname" /></span>
  <input type="submit" value="Test">
</form>
```

I would kindly discourage you from using `[A-Z][a-z]+`, a person name like `Đuro` will return a nice error since not an `A-Z` character.
Also, I'd use `.trim()` and convert the first character automatically to **uppercase** - for a better user experience. Seeing `roko` being converted automatically to `Roko` from your program - without throwing nonsense errors and stopping my progress - would be quite a nice experience.
In any way you should find a better regex.

Answer (score 0):

For info, since it doesn't give any javascript hints:

HTML5 allows to test a pattern with the attribute pattern:

If maybe not to be used in real life yet, it is a fast way to test your regular expression.

> https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#form.data.pattern
>
> https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text
>
> http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern

```css
input:valid {/* empty doesn't trigger errors, so it is valid :( unless required */
  border-color:green;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 3px green;
    }
input:invalid {
  border-color:red;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 3px tomato
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <p>The pattern from your question</p>  
  <input type="text" name="test" pattern="^[A-Z][a-z]+$" placeholder="^[A-Z][a-z]" required />
  </form>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan agreed, that's why i mention caniuse ;) ,  but usefull to know, i guess Safari won't take a decade to fix this